# "Error in f: Invalid dimension or metric:" then batching data with googleAnalyticsR in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, google-analytics-api

I have to build a Shiny-Board, there I need to get more then 10k rows from the Google Analytics Reporting API. For this I use my own Google API-Project 
Doing this in RStudio works perfectly and I can get as much rows I want. If I do this in shiny I don´t get a problem getting less then 10k rows if I want to get more I get the following Error:

```
2017-08-17 14:12:55> Fetched: landingPagePath city date sourceMedium sessions newUsers bounceRate pageviewsPerSession avgSessionDuration transactions transactionRevenue. [10000] total results out of a possible [190119], Start-Index: 1
2017-08-17 14:12:55> Batching data into [20] calls.
Request #: 1 : 10001 : 20001 : 30001 : 40001 : 50001 : 60001 : 70001 : 80001 : 90001
2017-08-17 14:12:57> Request to profileId:  ()
Warning: Error in f: Invalid dimension or metric: 
Stack trace (innermost first):
    114: f
    113: FUN
    112: lapply
    111: googleAuthR::gar_batch
    110: FUN
    109: lapply
    108: googleAuthR::gar_batch_walk
    107: batchData
    106: loop_ids
    105: f
    104: with_shiny
    103: eventReactiveHandler [#405]
     83: gadata
     82: renderDataTable [#511]
     81: func
     80: origRenderFunc
     79: output$Con_Table
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
```

I can call the same query in a differnt Timeframe (to don´t hit the 10k Limit) and it works with the dimensions and metrics.

Here is the query I use:

## Auth

```
options("googleAuthR.webapp.client_id" = app_config$gaClientId)
        options("googleAuthR.webapp.client_secret" = app_config$gaClientSecret)
        options("googleAuthR.scopes.selected" =c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"))
        ## Get auth code from return URL
        token <- callModule(googleAuth, "login")

         ga_accounts <- reactive({
            req(token())

            with_shiny(ga_account_list, shiny_access_token = token())

        })

        selected_id <- callModule(authDropdown, "auth_menu", ga.table = ga_accounts)
```

## Query Data

```
 ga<-with_shiny(google_analytics,
                               id = gaid,
                               start=(as.character(input$datestart)), end=(as.character(input$dateend)), 
                               metrics = metric, 
                               dimensions = dime,max=99999999, 
                               shiny_access_token = token())
```

Some more information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

> packageVersion("googleAnalyticsR")
[1] ‘0.4.1’
```

Does anybody has a idea what I´m missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Edmondson the problem is solved. Instead of using the V3 Version of the API just use the V4 Version. The call looks like this then:

```
ga<-with_shiny(google_analytics_4,
                               id = gaid,
                                date_range = c(as.character(input$datestart), as.character(input$dateend)), 
                               metrics = metric, 
                               dimensions = dime,anti_sample = TRUE,
                               shiny_access_token = token())
```